# Excel cell limit of 32K characters?

Tags: mysql, excel, unicode

Microsoft specify that Excel has a 32K character limit per cell.

Whereas MYSQL documents a 64K byte limit per field.

So which is larger? Or smaller :-) I am unclear what a "character" is in this Unicode (utf-8? utf-16? other?) compliant world. Whatever that means.

Thanks

Comment: MySQL has 64KiB limit per *row*, but the limit for individual fields can be greater (if stored outside the row e.g. `LONGTEXT` etc).  The number of *characters* that represents for a *string type* depends on the character set in which *you choose* to store your data.  UTF-16 always requires 2 bytes per character; whereas UTF-8 characters are variable-length, each requiring between 1 and 4 bytes.

Comment: While I'm not sure if this is a question, I'm pretty sure that that ^^^ is an answer

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's limit per column is 4GB.  However, you need to specify the appropriate datatype to get to that limit -- `LONGTEXT` or `LONGBLOB`.  If there is a 64KB limit somewhere, it can be worked around.

In MySQL, the datatype and, if relevant, the `CHARACTER SET` determine the maximum *bytes* per *character*.  Example: 4 for `utf8mb4`.  The `VARBINARY` datatype counts in *bytes*; `VARCHAR` counts in *characters*.  `TEXT` and `BLOB` have a limit of 64K *bytes*.  But, there are `MEDIUMTEXT` and `LONGTEXT` datatypes.